# New install 12.4 LTS no network conncections

Tags: 12.04, networking, broadcom

I installed 12.4 LTS on a Dell D520 with Broadcom 1390.  No network connection, wired or wireless is recognized.  No network is displayed for wired or wireless in network connection box.  Both wired and wireless network connections worked under Windows XP before Ubuntu install.  I verified ethernet cable connection with another computer. Did not do dual install - replaced XP.  I found solution for wireless card, but that requires wired connection.

How can I make it recognize a network?

Answer (score 0):

found some links who have same problem like you and their problem solved but its fof ubuntu 11.04 versions i think they work for 12.04 too

http://blog.tech4him.com/broadcom-wireless-on-ubuntu-11-04-and-11-10/

northd_tech solution at end of page in
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11203404#post11203404

but first you can try getting drivers from additional drivers(to see if open source drivers are available) or reinstalling the os to see whether they work after reinstalling

Comment: check these two links too   http://odzangba.wordpress.com/2007/06/09/wireless-on-dell-latitude-d520-with-ubuntu/

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1780376